# CakePHP Facebook login “given URL not allowed by application configuration”

Tags: php, facebook, cakephp

I am trying to integrate Facebook Connect in my website I am devloping at home, however when I try to Login, I get: "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration" error.

My login URL is:

```
   http://localhost/eng/login
```

I tried to enter it in URL settings in Facebook Developers Page, but nothing changed.

Comment: What have you set in the facebook app for allowed urls?

Comment: What do you mean in facebook app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

facebook and google only allow login attemps from the given url origin you setup in there configuration file. for example in facebook under the app `Settings` tab you define your `SiteUrl`.

SiteUrl: `http://example.com`

with this configured site, facebook only allow login attemps from `example.com`. therefore your login attempt fails because you're on the local domain `localhost`.

but you can "trick" facebook with wildcard domains like [xip.io](http://xip.io). facebook disallow siteurl that point to local domains, so insert `http://localhost` in the facebook app settings would fail.

setup your siteurl in facebook like this `127.0.0.1.xip.io` (which points on requests to the ip `127.0.0.1`) and configure your local apache server to listen on `http://127.0.0.1`. after that you can now use the facebook login on your local apache environment.

Comment: How can I configure my vhost sitename?

Comment: After adding virtual host with xip.io domain, nothing happens as `localhost.xip.io` redirects me to xip.op domain site.

Comment: `NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost.xip.io
    ServerAlias localhost.xip.io
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\app\webroot"
</VirtualHost>` Does not work :(

Comment: sry my mistake use the ip ``127.0.0.1`` - ``127.0.0.1.xip.io`` on vhost just have the apache server running on ``http://127.0.0.1/``

Comment: u mean everywhere 127.0.0.1 instead of `localhost`, even in facebook app settings, app url as `http:/127.0.0.1.xip.io` ? :o

Comment: yeah fb > ``127.0.0.1.xip.io`` and apache on ``127.0.0.1``

Comment: I changed all localhost's to 127.0.0.1 and it works! Thank you very much for your time and effort :)